# Homepage banner strangely blurry on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a banner to use above-the-fold on my homepage instead of a slider.

It works perfectly when viewed on a computer, even when I resize the window of the browser to match the width of a cell phone's screen.

However, when I view the page from an actual cell phone, the background image is blurry and incredibly zoomed in. Not sure how to fix it, would appreciate your help.

```js
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
  const scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Adjusting background-position for the parallax effect
  $('#custom-banner').css({
    'background-position': '50% ' + (-scrollPos / 6) + "px"
  });

  // Adjust this function for the bannertext position
  const bannerHeight = $('#custom-banner').height();
  let newTop = 20 + (scrollPos * 0.1); // Adjust the factor (0.1 here) for a faster or slower parallax effect

  // Make sure it doesn't move outside of the banner
  if (newTop < 20) newTop = 20;
  if (newTop > bannerHeight) newTop = bannerHeight;

  $('#bannertext').css({
    'top': newTop + '%',
    'opacity': 1 - (scrollPos / 250)
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    EasyPeasyParallax();
  });
});
```

```css
#custom-banner h1 {
  font: 700 2.8em/1.2;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

#custom-banner p {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Cormorant Infant", Sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#custom-banner {
  background: url(https://houniqueconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/an-awards-bg-par1.jpg) no-repeat fixed 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#bannertext {
  width: 35em;
  position: absolute;
  /* Changed from fixed to absolute */
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  border: .5em solid #fff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 2em 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Media Queries for smaller screens */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #custom-banner {
    height: 70vh;
  }
  #custom-banner h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  #bannertext {
    width: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-banner">
  <div id="bannertext">
    <h1>Los Angeles’ Premier Home Remodeling Contractor</h1>
    <p>Finest Construction Since 1992.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem using [the code you’ve included](https://donald.au/bugs/so-77478001.html) and my iPhone 13 mini. So maybe the problem is being caused by code that you have **not** included.

Comment: @BrettDonald, Did you try going to the url from the screenshot? The html includes exclusive ids and classes, not sure what other code could affect the issue, but my website is on wordpress and I'm utilizing Elementor

Comment: Yes, when I visit [H&O Unique Construction](https://houniqueconstruction.com) on my mobile, I can see the problem. But on Stack Overflow, we answer specific documented questions, we don’t fix broken websites. Your question needs to be self-contained; it needs to contain everything someone needs to reproduce the problem **without** referring to your website. I’m happy to help further, but only once you’ve edited your question to contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BrettDonald I appreciate you checking it out. I will try to figure what other code is affecting the banner and circle back